# WPF Toolkit Datagrid - Show detail rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a WPFToolkit DataGrid Control. The user should be able to toggle row details for individual rows. Details can be open for multiple rows at the same time.

To display or hide row details the user has to check or uncheck a checkbox within the first grid column.

How can I make the grid show or hide row details using a checkbox column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Just add an Trigger on the IsChecked
   property of the checkbox, and then
   set the Visibility of the property
   of the row details to the property
   of the IsChecked property
2. simply bind the IsChecked to the
   Visibility property of the row
   details